# React: how to access component function from a click event on vis.js edge?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vis.js, react-graph-vis

I have a react component, like:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  // ...

  _openDialog = () => {
    this.setState({ isDialogOpen: true });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="tree_graph_div">
          <Graph
            graph={graph}
            events={{
              selectEdge: function(event) {
                var { nodes, edges } = event;
                if (edges.length == 1) {
                  //I want to access _openDialog here with edge id
                }
              }
            }}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Dialog />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The graph is created with react-graph-vis.

I want to make the selectEdge event to handle: open the dialog for this edge_id.

The event have the edge id, but how I can access back to the function _openDialog?

I tried this, but this here stands for the Graph object, not the App.

Thanks

---

I tried change Graph to this with arrow function:

```
<Graph graph={graph}
  events={{
    selectEdge: (event) => {
      debugger;
    }
  }}
/>
```

But by stop in debugger point, the "this" doesn't have the function _openDialog.

Comment: If you give `selectEdge` an arrow function instead (`(event) => { ... }`), you can just write `this._openDialog(edges);`.

Comment: I tried, this is not working. "this" is the graph here, it's not the App so doesn't have function _openDialog(). Or might be I misunderstood what your mean?

Comment: Yes, that will work. Put a `debugger;` in `_openDialog` and you will see that it will be called.

Comment: This module react-graph-vis is not working. This module has issues unable to install it, not sure how its working for you

Comment: @Tholle, It works! why? As I changed above new edit, the debugger point didn't show this has function _openDialog, which is logically reasonable because this refers to the Graph as I though. .. It's amazing! Tnx a lot!

Comment: @JieHu Great! You can read about how [arrow functions work here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). I'm not sure why you couldn't see it in the debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the function given to `selectEdge` to an arrow function to use the enclosing lexical scope instead, which has `_openDialog` on `this`.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  // ...

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="tree_graph_div">
          <Graph
            graph={graph}
            events={{
              selectEdge: (event) => {
                var { nodes, edges } = event;
                if (edges.length == 1) {
                  this._openDialog(edges);
                }
              }
            }}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Dialog />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I just googled this term for react and got pretty good understanding: https://toddmotto.com/es6-arrow-functions-syntaxes-and-lexical-scoping/.